# How to groupby and convert data to NaN values if there is at least 1 NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all rows for a specific `CODE` if there is at least one NaN value in `PPTOT` by `CODE`.

This is my `df`:

```
         CODE   MONTH_DAY PPTOT
0        113250   01-01    8.4
1        113250   01-02    9.3
2        113250   01-03   NaN
3        113250   01-04   12.7
4        113250   01-05    7.7
        ...     ...    ...
16975  47E94706   12-27    5.0
16976  47E94706   12-28   10.2
16977  47E94706   12-29    0.2
16978  47E94706   12-30    0.3
16979  47E94706   12-31    2.0
```

There is one NaN value in `PPTOT` for 113250 `CODE` so all values with `CODE` 113250 must be converted to NaN

Expected result:

```
         CODE   MONTH_DAY PPTOT
0        113250   01-01    NaN
1        113250   01-02    NaN
2        113250   01-03    NaN
3        113250   01-04    NaN
4        113250   01-05    NaN
        ...     ...    ...
16975  47E94706   12-27    5.0
16976  47E94706   12-28   10.2
16977  47E94706   12-29    0.2
16978  47E94706   12-30    0.3
16979  47E94706   12-31    2.0
```

So i tried this code:

```
notnan=pd.DataFrame()

for code, data in df.groupby('CODE'):
    data.dropna(subset=['PPTOT'], how='any')
    notnan=notnan.append(data)
```

But in `notnan` i'm getting values with NaN

I don't understand why.

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to drop all rows or set them to NaN, it's different? Because your expect output is not what you try to code.

Comment: @Corralien drop all rows, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> df.loc[df['PPTOT'].notnull().groupby(df['CODE']).transform('all')]

           CODE MONTH_DAY  PPTOT
16975  47E94706     12-27    5.0
16976  47E94706     12-28   10.2
16977  47E94706     12-29    0.2
16978  47E94706     12-30    0.3
16979  47E94706     12-31    2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a toy data frame like so;

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'value': [np.nan, 'A', 'B', 'B']})
>>> df
   group value
0      1   NaN
1      1     A
2      2     B
3      2     B
```

Within groups, test whether any are `nan`. If any are, then substitute `nan`. Otherwise, fill with existing values.

```
>>> df.groupby('group').transform(lambda s: np.where(s.isnull().any(), np.nan, s))
  value
0   NaN
1   NaN
2     B
3     B
```

Reassign with overwrite to complete.

Answer (score 1):

based on you label and df:

```
df['PPTOT'] = df.groupby('CODE')['PPTOT'].transform(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().any() else x)
```